# stackexchange websites keep asking for my proxy authentication

Tags: support

Does this happen to anyone else? I'm behind a proxy at work and every few minutes I have to enter the proxy authentication when I'm stackexchange websites. This doesn't happen to most other websites where I only have to enter it at the start of my browsing session.

Comment: Looks like your proxy is choking on websockets. See [My corporate proxy doesn't support web sockets, which makes Stack Exchange a pain to use](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130053).

Answer (score 3):

No.  Sounds like the proxy server you are going through is breaking things.